# Can I create a Desktop Shortcut/Alias to a Folder from the Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, desktop, alias

I'd like to create a desktop shortcut to a specific folder, buried deep within `~/Library/`. Library is Hidden by default in Lion, and I'd like to keep it that way, for a variety of reasons. Is there a one-step, command line action I can use, to create a desktop shortcut to a given path? I'd like to avoid solutions that involve unhiding the Library, creating the Alias using Finder, and rehiding it. I know how to do that, but for my purposes, a single line that can be pasted into Terminal and be done with it would be preferable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this on Terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop
ln -s ~/Library/path/to/folder
```

Comment: I think you meant `ln -s ~/Library/path/to/folder folder`. One minor disadvantage to this method (ie symlinking) is that the link will be broken if the "original" (ie the target) is moved or renamed.

Comment: The second argument `folder` is not required. If you omit it, `ln` creates a link named the same as the original folder.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I got an error before, but I must've mistyped something.

Comment: I know what it was - you can't have a trailing slash!

Comment: OSX aliases are *not* symbolic links. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165799/why-doesnt-this-simple-applescript-work#comment14645816_11166109

Comment: This is not correct - an OSX alias is not a Unix symbolic link. For the correct answer see the solution posted by @Kelvin: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51712/109837

Comment: Still works on Mac 10.12 and it's nice and simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

It's possible to do it in one line of Terminal. Let's say you want to alias to the file "/Users/me/Library/Preferences/org.herf.Flux.plist".

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder"' -e 'make new alias to file (posix file "/Users/me/Library/Preferences/org.herf.Flux.plist") at desktop' -e 'end tell'
```

You should replace `to file` with `to folder` if you have a folder.

Here's a shell script that allows you pass in a file or folder path to create the alias:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -f "$1" ]]; then
  type="file"
else
  if [[ -d "$1" ]]; then 
    type="folder"
  else
    echo "Invalid path or unsupported type"
    exit 1
  fi
fi

osascript <<END_SCRIPT
tell application "Finder"
   make new alias to $type (posix file "$1") at desktop
end tell
END_SCRIPT
```

If you name this script `make-alias.sh`, `chmod u+x make-alias.sh` and put it in `/usr/local/bin`, you can run e.g. `make-alias.sh ~/Library/Preferences`.

Comment: Will `~/Library/Preferences/org.herf.Flux.plist"` work, or does the username need to be explicitly included in the Terminal command?

Comment: I just tried using `~` and it doesn't work with the one-line `osascript` command. I suggest using the script file instead, because the `~` is converted automatically.

Comment: Hmm. Seems to break on filenames with spaces such as `/Library/Application Support/`

Comment: If you're using the bash script, you should put the filename in single quotes if it has any spaces or special characters. However, this will prevent `~` from being expanded. The best thing is not to use quotes, and to tab complete the filename so bash will properly "escape" the special characters. E.g. type `~/Library/Application` then press tab. If `Application Support` was the only match, the shell should have inserted a backslash before the space. You can also manually use a backslash to escape.

Comment: Note that the spaces/special chars problem would exist in any solution - the shell can't know that you meant to pass 1 parameter rather than 2 separate ones.

Comment: You could also coerce to alias instead of specifying the type: `osascript -e "tell app \"Finder\" to make new alias to (posix file \"$1\") as alias at desktop"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

get_abs() {
  # $1 : relative filename
  echo "$(cd "$(dirname "$1")" && pwd)/$(basename "$1")"
}


if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]; then
    echo "mkalias: specify 'from' and 'to' paths" >&2
    exit 1
fi

from=$(eval get_abs $1)  
todir=$(dirname $(eval get_abs $2))
toname=$(basename $(eval get_abs $2))
if [[ -f "$from" ]]; then
    type="file"
elif [[ -d "$from" ]]; then
    type="folder"
else
    echo "mkalias: invalid path or unsupported type: '$from'" >&2
    exit 1
fi

osascript <<EOF
tell application "Finder"
   make new alias to $type (posix file "$from") at (posix file "$todir")
   set name of result to "$toname"
end tell
EOF
```

Comment: An explanation of how the script works would be useful

Comment: Same as script above but without need for realpath

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to target the link at a specific folder (or give it a specific name), you can use `set name of result to "…"` as in

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]; then
    echo "mkalias: specify 'from' and 'to' paths" >&2
    exit 1
fi

from="$(realpath $1)"
todir="$(dirname $(realpath $2))"
toname="$(basename $(realpath $2))"
if [[ -f "$from" ]]; then
    type="file"
elif [[ -d "$from" ]]; then
    type="folder"
else
    echo "mkalias: invalid path or unsupported type: '$from'" >&2
    exit 1
fi

osascript <<EOF
tell application "Finder"
   make new alias to $type (posix file "$from") at (posix file "$todir")
   set name of result to "$toname"
end tell
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who would like a python solution, here is a function wrapping applescript, then calling subprocess.call:

```
def applescript_finder_alias(theFrom, theTo):
    """
    (theFrom, theTo)
    create a short/alias
    theFrom, theTo: relative or abs path, both folder or both file
    """
    # https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51709
    applescript = '''
    tell application "Finder"
       make new alias to %(theType)s (posix file "%(theFrom)s") at (posix file "%(todir)s")
       set name of result to "%(toname)s"
    end tell
    '''
    def myesp(cmdString):
        import os, inspect, tempfile, subprocess
        caller = inspect.currentframe().f_back
        cmd =  cmdString % caller.f_locals

        fd, path = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='.applescript')
        try:
            with os.fdopen(fd, 'w') as tmp:
                tmp.write(cmd.replace('"','\"').replace("'","\'")+'\n\n')
            subprocess.call('osascript ' + path, shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")
        finally:
            os.remove(path)
        return None
    import os
    theFrom = os.path.abspath(theFrom)
    theTo = os.path.abspath(theTo)
    if os.path.isfile(theFrom): 
        theType = 'file'
    else:
        theType = 'folder'
    todir = os.path.dirname(theTo)
    toname = os.path.basename(theTo)
    myesp(applescript)
```