# How do I create Windows-like shortcuts (with arguments) from the command line?

Tags: terminal, finder, command-line, automator

I've been searching and searching for a process on OS X that creates something as simple and elegant as Windows shortcuts.  At the user's direction on install, I need to create a shortcut-like item that contains command-line arguments to the installed application, and that can be placed in the Dock like a normal application with an icon.

I have found that I can do exactly what I want to do from the Automator application: Select "Application", enter the command line, save it, copy and paste the icon, etc.  However, the process is all *manual*.  I can't do that in an automated install of the application.

I cannot seem to find a way to do these Automator steps from the command line (which would be required during installation of my application) using something like Apple Script (osacript).

In what is [more of a hack than an actual solution](https://superuser.com/questions/271678/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-dock-items), I have also found that I can manipulate the installed application's Info.plist file, replacing the CFBundleExecutable value with a shell script that does an "open -a ... --args ...", but this requires some rather unbelievable hoops just to make it work.

I am also aware of Finder aliases ([Can I create a Desktop Shortcut/Alias to a Folder from the Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51709/can-i-create-a-desktop-shortcut-alias-to-a-folder-from-the-terminal)), which might also solve the problem, however there doesn't appear to be a way to add command-line arguments.

Everything seems to require either user interaction, or hackish file moving and manipulation.  So the question is:  **How do I achieve this simple and elegant Windows-like shortcut mechanism under OS X without requiring these things?**

Just to be clear, *launching* the application with arguments is not a problem (e.g., "open -a <apppath> --args ...").  Creating something that the user can manage *like* an application (i.e., Dock) that actually launches the app with arguments doesn't seem to be something very easily accomplished under OS X.

Comment: See this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/260467/open-shell-script-from-finder-interactively/260485#260485

Comment: Thanks for the link, Allan. I did not know about ".command" files.  However, this is yet just another *partial* solution to this problem.  I can create the ".command" file on the Desktop, but it displays the ".command" extension, it will *not* Dock (like an alias or an Automator "Application"), and it flashes a terminal window when you double-click on it to launch.  This is really not much different that just creating a regular shell script.

Comment: It doesn't need to have the `.command` extension.  It could be `.sh` or nothing at all.  Bash is a flexible thing.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what adding the ".command" extension to the script even achieves here (according to the sited article).

I know how to write Bash scripts, and I can achieve what I need from there.  However, that was not the gist of my post.  My question was about Windows-like shortcuts that behave like applications on the OS X desktop.

I'm guessing at this point that it's simply not possible to automate this process under OS X like you can under Windows.

Comment: A Windows shortcut is nothing more than a file with a command on it.  In macOS (and any \*NIX for that matter), *everything is a file*, so if you want a "shortcut" you need to create a file with the commands you want to execute.  So, can you get what you are looking for in macOS *like* in Windows?  Yes.  Is it the same way Windows does it?  No.  macOS is **not** Windows.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your issue, but as far as I know you can create an application over Script Editor with an icon and save it on the dock, launching a bash script with whatever arguments you need to open another app.